# Save an equality in Mathematica

Tags: export

I am trying to do the simplest thing, just to export
`f = Log[z]`
in a .m file. I don't want just to export the `Log[z]` but the full equality.

Answer (score 3):

This works for me

```
ClearAll[f, z];
eq = f == Log[z];
Export["t.txt", eq]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
>cat t.txt
f == Log[z]
```

And if you meant `=`

```
ClearAll[f, z];
f = Log[z];
Export["t2.txt", "f = " <> ToString@f]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
>cat t2.txt
f = Log[z]
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually I found that one can do the following without, being as simple as it can be:
Define the function:
`f = Log[z]`
and then, rather than `Export` do `Save["/path/file.m",f]` and it saves the whole equality. I find it simpler. I am not sure if there is a deeper difference and the potential caveats, but for this simple case it works.